# Access several SSH servers via a single jump SSH server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I would like to access several different SSH servers (i.e. `dest1`, `dest2`) via a single SSH bastion server (i.e. `bastion`).  I would like to avoid logging into the bastion server each time I want to connect to a different SSH server.  How do I do this?

I tried adding my public key to the bastion server.  However, the bastion server disabled public key logon and requires password logon.  (The password is a combination of a password and the output from a Yubikey.)

I tried setting up dynamic port and then do local port forwarding through the dynamic port.

I setup a dynamic port with the following command.  I am enter my password when prompted.

```
ssh -f -N -o KeepAlive=yes -D 127.0.0.1:55555 -l user bastion
```

I then use the following command to setup the local port forwarding.

```
ssh -vvv -f -N -L 127.0.0.1:44444:dest1:22 -p 55555 localhost
```

The command does not work.  I get the following output and error message.

```
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 55555.
debug1: Connection established.
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

If that worked, then I could simply do the following to access dest1:

```
ssh -p 44444 me@localhost
```

Later, I would set up another local port forwarding for dest2 and access dest2 in a similar way.

**Edit:** Note: I am using Cygwin.

Comment: Are you able to use `ssh -J user@bastion user@dest1` or `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@bastion" user@dest1`, even if it's for a single connection only?

Comment: @grawity Both commands work but I have to log into the bastion every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original example**

Your attempt did not work because *that is not how `-D` is supposed to be used*. It doesn't create a direct listener that you can simply SSH to. Instead, it creates a **SOCKS** listener, which is only compatible with apps that can use a SOCKS4/5 proxy to tell the "server" what host they want first – that's where the "dynamic" part comes from.

Your second command would have worked if the first one used `-L 55555:localhost:22` instead, but honestly the two are completely **redundant** – it doesn't save you any auth checks or anything. In fact you end up authenticating to bastion more times than necessary.

Just use `ssh -L 44444:dest1:22 bastion` directly. (If you have multiple tunnels, you can specify multiple -L's on this command.) *Then* you will be able to use `ssh -p 44444 me@localhost` to access dest1.

1. Establish tunnel: `ssh user@bastion -f -N -L 40001:dest1:22 -L 40002:dest2:22`
2. Connect to dest1: `ssh localhost -p 40001`

**Alternative 1**

You can go in the other direction and use *only* the `-D 55555` dynamic tunnel option. However, you cannot simply use it with `ssh -p`; you need additional software that can act as a SOCKS client. One example is socat, which you can use as an ssh `ProxyCommand` helper:

1. Establish tunnel: `ssh user@bastion -f -N -D 55555`
2. Connect to dest1: `ssh dest1 -o ProxyCommand="socat stdio socks4a:localhost:[%h]:%p,socksport=55555"`

**Alternative 2**

You can use `ControlPath` and `ControlMaster` options to tell the initial *ssh* client to act as a proxy for other clients:

1. Establish connection: `ssh user@bastion -S ~/.ssh/S.bastion -f -N -M`
2. Open interactive shells: `ssh bastion -S ~/.ssh/S.bastion`
3. Connect to other servers: `ssh bastion -S ~/.ssh/S.bastion -t "ssh dest1"`
4. Add tunnels: `ssh bastion -S ~/.ssh/S.bastion -O forward -L 12345:dest1:22`
5. Remove tunnels: `ssh bastion -S ~/.ssh/S.bastion -O cancel -L 12345:dest1:22`

(SSHv2 makes no assumptions about what kind of channels will be created over the connection. Just like one SSHv2 connection can carry any number of TCP-tunnels or ssh-agent requests, it can also carry any number of interactive and non-interactive shell sessions – not necessarily 0 or 1.)

The ~/.ssh/config file options would look like:

```
Host bastion
    # Automatically keep a background connection (-M) after any use
    ControlMaster auto
    # Keep idle background connections for at least this long
    ControlPersist 1h

Host *
    # Default value for -S
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/S.%r@%h:%p
```

Comment: I setup `~/.ssh/config` exactly as above but I added `HostName` and `User` to the `Host bastion` section.  I then executed #1 and #2.  #2 gives an error of `mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Connection reset by peer`.  The bash shell for #1 gives an error of `mm_receive_fd: no message header` and `mux_master_process_new_session: failed to receive fd 0 from slave`.  What am I doing wrong?  I am using `Cygwin`.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a Cygwin bug.